# What would be a good training regiment/exercises for BJJ beginner?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, exercise, strength, flexibility, fitness

Peace, Love, and Divine Blessings to all.  I'm 6'0Ft, 150 lbs, not very flexible, and have not worked out consistently in a long period of time but always desired to learn self-defense.  My goal is not necessarily to be a master or the greatest ever but for practical self-defense purposes (protection for myself, my loved ones, and anyone else who I may assist in a time of need).

I have never really been into weight lifting and very much into just being strictly calisthenics, cardio, and stretching.  If you can assist in those areas that would be truly helpful.  I'm not trying to regulate any wisdom that is shared with me but that's just my preference. I ask this question in all humility seeking to expand and grow in my livelihood.  Thank you very much.

Comment: A little more detail, please. What are you doing now? Have you started BJJ classes, yet? If not, I think your questions will be answered with simply: Attend classes regularly, and you will be working on exactly what you need to be working on in order to get better at BJJ.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Peace and thank you for your response. At this juncture, I have not started classes but do hope so in the near future. Right now, I haven't started working out yet but I do a lot of walking (miles) and yard work, for what its worth.

Comment: Then what I said is true. You shouldn't worry too much about getting into better shape to prepare for BJJ. Your BJJ instructor will understand. Even if you can't do a single pushup, or you can't run more than 1/4 mile before walking again, it doesn't matter. Nobody is going to think anything less of you. And after attending regular BJJ classes, your physical fitness will improve a lot. They'll notice when that happens, but they won't care if you're very out of shape in the beginning. So don't worry about it. Just go and do your first class.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Makes too much sense. I appreciate you and your response beloved.